# Fitnesse Check Not Equal

Tags: java, testing, fitnesse

Inside Fitnesse [DoFixture](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.FitLibraryFixtures.DoFixture), you can use `check` keyword to compare one of the objects with an expected value. I was wondering if there is a `check not equal` that exists to make sure the expected and actual do not match up.

I have tried using that set of keywords but it is not supported. There is a `reject` keyword for DoFixtures, but it does not accomplish the goal. Anyone know of a method? For a testing framework, it seems like it should be obvious, but I've had a rough time digging through the [UserGuide](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide).

Example:

```
|check not equal| guid | c1acff01-e45b-4b7d-b6f5-84f8830ef6b4 |
```

Scenario Pass: guid != c1acff01-e45b-4b7d-b6f5-84f8830ef6b4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find this type of test condition, so instead, I put the logic inside the Fixture code with the expectation to return true when `a != b`. In the Fit code, I had the following:

`|check|guidsNotEqual|true|`

Answer (score 0):

With fitSharp you can have

```
|check|mymethod|fail[myvalue]|
```

This will pass if mymethod is not equal to myvalue.  I don't think this works with the Java FitLibrary.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I am working with Java and not fitSharp. I think I found a solution in which I can use the fixture to do the not equals logic to return an expected boolean value. Not the ideal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option (might be added after the question was asked). It is possible to check for something not equal by using 'check not'.
So

```
|check not|this is true|false|
```

will return true